# how do i solve: The component **** does not have a resource identified by the URI

Tags: wpf

I have a small application where i load some assemblies as plugins. All is well until i load an assembly with a WebBrowser (I assume its Windows Forms) then my host application extepts with the error:

The component **** does not have a resource identified by the URI

I tried to remove the WebBrowser control but little did it help. Does anyone know how to solve this problem or help me find another way of browsing a web page in WPF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution: The assembly i loaded was "Client profile", argh :-)

Comment: +1 because you answered your own question, even if it does not fix my problem ;-)

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Client Profile"? Was it a project setting? Were you just loading the wrong assembly?

Comment: Client Profile refers to the .net framework selected in the project settings.  I honestly don't know what it does other than cause problems.